# Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain"

Tags: javascript, html

Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I get this error in chrome after trying to add this line to my HTML code:

```
<script type="module">import * as hello from './__target__/hello.js'; window.hello = hello;</script>
<!-- From the official documentation of Transcrypt -->
```

I've been trying to fix for hours, someone suggested to change the type to text/javascript and to use the src tag (src = './__ target__/hello.js') but I need some imports in hello.js

**FIXED:**
Ok I was starting the server with 'python -m http.server' from command line, I just replaced it with this python2 script:

```
#Use to create local host
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
Handler.extensions_map.update({
    ".js": "application/javascript",
});

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print ("Serving at port", PORT)
print(Handler.extensions_map[".js"])
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: The error you show is a server-side error: the server should be telling your browser that this is a js file, not a plain text file. So start by putting your script in a file (don't inline it) and then link to that .js file with a `<script src="..." type="module"></script>`. If that yields the same error, your server is not sending files with their correct mime-type, and you should fix that (almost every server can do this for you out-of-the-box, so just google for how to configure yours to correctly add the mime type header)

Comment: Are you sure that you are including the right file?

Comment: I'm using python -m http.server to try my application, how should I setup content headers and mime-types?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , I am getting the same issue after building the same application for android, how could I change the mime type if the program is not working on a server?

Comment: Face the same issue. Yet strangely when I launch http.server with python 3.8.5, it is ok, but when I launch http.server with python 3.8.10 at another computer, the issue occurs.

Answer (score 19):

This question (and the script involved) really helped me a lot. I have modified the script provided in the answer to make it compatible with python3.

```py
#Use to create local host
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 1337

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
Handler.extensions_map.update({
      ".js": "application/javascript",
});

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The notable changes are:-

1. Changed **SimpleHTTPServer** to **http.server**. From python3 onwards , SimpleHTTPServer has become a part of http.server
2. Changed **SocketServer** module to **socketserver**

The functions are backward compatible.

Answer (score 8):

Your web server is serving `hello.js` with `Content-Type: text/plain`, which is disallowed by the browser because it's not JavaScript.

You need to update your web server configuration so that it serves that file (and presumably all `*.js` files) with `Content-Type: application/javascript`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what if I am building it on android using cordova (so without any server)? In this case I get The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of ""

Comment: @FabrizioApuzzo - `application/javascript` is a JavaScript MIME type. Again: The server needs to serve the file correctly.

Comment: Ok, but I am using a framework that converts html5 to native mobile applications, so I do not have any server to configure

Comment: @FabrizioApuzzo - There's probably a server embedded in there (there usually is). You'll have to dive into the documentation.

Comment: Hello, I'm a JS learner, I get this same error when I type this in console although my file is json: `import('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ljharb/json-file-plus/master/package.json').then(m=>
console.log(m));` What can I do? I also tried this: `a=document.createElement('script');
a.setAttribute('type','module');
a.textContent = "import * as name from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ljharb/json-file-plus/master/package.json';
console.log(name);"
document.body.append(a)`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is renaming the Javascript file to `*.mjs` instead of `*.js`. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/75896

Answer (score 2):

I am hosting my Angular compiled website with IIS and had to change the mime type in it for `.js` files from `application/javascript` to `text/javascript`, then it worked for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Windows 10 + Django 2.2.25) it was windows registry Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.js has a Content Type key set to text/plain. Changing it to application/javascript it worked again.
Django use view.py and static.py to serve static file (static.serve) that uses mimetype (from Python library). mimetype.py call mimetypes.guess_type()

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed the registry entry from:

[image: Before]

to

[image: after]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score 0):

This is the error log:

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Rt5.png)

**FIXDED:**

In my case (Windows 11 Pro) i edit the registy (regedit.exe) for the .js extension.

In particularly i had to edit the `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js`:

***FROM:***

[Content-Type=text/plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZifF.png)

***TO:***

[Content-Type=text/javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2egk.png)

This solved the problem for me.

References:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)
- [Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/the-browsers-recognize-js-files-as-mime-type/2be5ed09-4f14-49a5-ba20-bc70959903de)
- [Github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32350)