# Nginx: Angular app with web components - script type="module" error

Tags: angular, nginx, ecmascript-6, server

I would like to serve an Angular 8 app with a simple Nginx server. Unfortunately, when I try to serve the app I receive the following error in Chrome:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I found several solutions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908927/failed-to-load-module-script-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-ty) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403478/es6-modules-in-local-files-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-typ) for instance) suggesting I should manually configure all `script` tags and add `type="javascript"`. However, in my case I cannot do this because my app contains **Web Components** that can only be loaded when the script type attribute is `type="module"`.

My Nginx configuration looks like this:

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http
{
    sendfile on;

    server {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/app;
        listen 9020;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location ~ \.css {
            add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
        }

        location ~ \.js {
            add_header  Content-Type    application/javascript;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know how I can configure either Angular or Nginx to serve javascript files (included by `script` tags in the `index.html`) which are of type "module"?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You should serve javascript which has a `type="module"` with mime type `text/javascript` as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules):

> .js files need to be loaded with a MIME-type of text/javascript (or another JavaScript-compatible MIME-type, but text/javascript is recommended), otherwise you'll get a strict MIME type checking error like "The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type".

That aside, your SPA config for nginx is not correct as it never reaches the .js location statement. You should add a `try_files` statement:

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/app;
    listen 9020;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.css$ {
        default_type text/css;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.js$ {
        default_type text/javascript;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the `try_files` hint! However, the JS files still cannot be recognized and the browser error **The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain"** remains...

Comment: @SparkFountain I've updated my answer using `default_type`

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to my assumption, I found that it doesn't make a difference whether I write `<script type="module">` or `script type="text/javascript"` in my *index.html*.

However, I simply forgot the part *text/* in the MIME type declaration, thus the files could not be resolved correctly. My bad. Now the correct solution to this problem is to replace all MIME types `module` by `text/javascript`.

The actual problem only seems to occur with Angular 8 and has been discussed since June 2019 [in this GitHub bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30835). Another solution based on my tech stack (Angular 8 + Nginx) would be to explictly declare a MIME type association in Nginx for module scripts like this:

```
http {
    types {
      module js;
    }
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # rest of your config...
}
```

(see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30835#issuecomment-583943657)