# Python server showing html as text rather than rendering it

Tags: python, html, http.server

I'm trying to make a server the long way for more control/ learning. when i try to make a simple one with bash i get mimetype errors.

I must be looking at this the wrong way but my server seems to make the browser render the html as text. the html i get in the browser is weird too.

any help would be mush appreciated!

**server.py**

```
from http.server import HTTPServer,BaseHTTPRequestHandler

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 7800

class FeedSpeedServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):


        if self.path == "/":
            self.path = 'index.html'
        
        try:
            
            self.send_header("content-type", "text/html")
            self.send_header("content-type", "text/javascript")
            self.send_header("content-type", "text/css")
            self.end_headers()
            self.file = open(self.path).read()
            self.wfile.write(self.file.encode())
            self.send_response(200)
            
        except:
            self.file = "file not found"
            self.send_response(404)


httpd = HTTPServer((HOST, PORT), FeedSpeedServer)
print("server running...")
httpd.serve_forever()
print("server Stopped")
```

My web browser shows this...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPwbP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - Figured it out.

So i was having problems with MIME types and java script modules. I have thrown away the server i tried making and found it way easier to just use simple `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` this post fixed everything for me - [Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908927/failed-to-load-module-script-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-ty)

Also, put .js on the end of your import paths like this:

```
import { FeedsSpeeds } from "./FeedsSpeeds.js";
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with `http.server` for Python, but common examples I see send the status code **first**, then the headers, then the content.

Also, the `Content-Type` must be a single value.
This worked for me:

```
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/":
            self.path = 'index.html'
        try:
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            self.file = open(self.path).read()
            self.wfile.write(self.file.encode())
        except:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.file = "file not found"
```

If you plan to serve css/javascript, you might want to check the file extension of `self.path` and set `self.send_header("content-type", "text/xxx")` accordingly. An example:

```
    extensions = {
        "html": "text/html",
        "css": "text/css",
        "js": "text/javascript",
        "plain": "text/plain"
    }

    def set_content_type(self):
        extension = self.path.split(".")[-1]
        if extension in self.extensions:
            return self.extensions[extension]

        return self.extensions["plain"]
```

and replace `self.send_header("content-type", "text/html")` with `self.set_content_type()`

Comment: Hi Thanks for getting back to me. I've been messing around with this for around 6 hours now and making very little progress. which way would you serve css/js?

Comment: awh thanks a bunch.

can i not just add all the content-type headers i will need manually?

I have actually noticed that on chrome the html renders fine but i still get an error which i have found to be related to me trying to be clever and use js modules (import/ export of classes)