# Error: "Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain"" in my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, python, html, mime

I am trying to use the unofficial [ChatGPT API](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/chatgpt-api/blob/main/src/chatgpt-unofficial-proxy-api.ts) in my JavaScript code, but I keep getting this error message:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I get no other errors, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908927/failed-to-load-module-script-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-ty) hasn't helped.

I am using the Python3 script from one of the answers to that question, but I still get this issue. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
import { ChatGPTUnofficialProxyAPI } from 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/github.com/transitive-bullshit/chatgpt-api/tree/main/src';

async function example() {
  const api = new ChatGPTUnofficialProxyAPI({
    accessToken: process.env.OPENAI_ACCESS_TOKEN
  })
  const res = await api.sendMessage('Hello World!');
  console.log(res.text);
};
```

The HTML page (where the function is being called) is just a button that is supposed to call this function.
I am new to JS so I don't really know what to do.